# Log normalizer for Multivariate Gaussian (Exponential Family Representation)

Tags: normal-distribution, exponential-family

I am searching for the **log normalizer based on the natural parameters** for the **multivariate gaussian** in the **exponential family** representation.
For the univariate gaussian, it is given by
$$
a(\eta) = \frac{-\eta_1^2}{4 \eta_2} - \frac{1}{2} log(-2\eta_2)
$$
(See e.g. https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/exponential-families.pdf)

For the multivariate gaussian, however, I am completly stuck and couldn't find any ressources stating it.
Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The log normalizer for the multivariate Gaussian is given by
\begin{equation}
                F(\Theta) = \frac{1}{4} tr(\Theta_2^{-1} \Theta_1 \Theta_1^T) - \frac{1}{2} log | \Theta_2 | + \frac{\mathcal{D}}{2} log \pi
            \end{equation}
with $\Theta = (\Theta_1, \Theta_2)$ being the natural parameters and $tr(\cdot)$ denoting the trace of a matrix.